Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'exactInputSingle')
When I run this script, this error keep showing

Contract Address: 0xe592427a0aece92de3edee1f18e0157c05861564
Error in getUniswapV3Rate: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'exactInputSingle')

Why is that? In ABI file this 'exactInputSingle' is already included
Snippet from my script:
async function getUniswapV3Rate(fromToken, toToken, amount) {
  try {
      const uniswapV3Router = new ethers.Contract(addresses.uniswapV3Router, UniswapV3RouterABI, provider);

      const params = {
          tokenIn: fromToken,
          tokenOut: toToken,
          fee: 3000,
          recipient: ethAddress,
          deadline: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60 * 20,
          amountIn: amount.toString(), // Ensure amount is a string
          amountOutMinimum: 0,
          sqrtPriceLimitX96: 0,
      };

      console.log('Params:', params);
      console.log('Contract Address:', addresses.uniswapV3Router);

      if (!uniswapV3Router.functions.exactInputSingle) {
          throw new Error('exactInputSingle method not found in Uniswap V3 Router ABI');
      }

      const quote = await uniswapV3Router.callStatic.exactInputSingle(params);
      console.log('Quote:', quote);

      return new BigNumber(quote.toString());
  } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error in getUniswapV3Rate:', error);
      return new BigNumber(0); // Return zero if there's an error

I tired to get current price rates of certain tokens from uniswapv3 router

What does this have to do with Python?

sorry its nothing to do with python. can you help me ?

you should create minimal repruducible code. it could because of many reasons
